# Getting rid of NA's in a single column?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I am a beginner R programmer using the tidyverse and skimr libraries in R Studio. I am having trouble computing a correlation (getting "NA" in response) which I assume is because one of my variables has missing values.

This is my attempted correlation:

```
cor(baby_data$mother_age, baby_data$father_age)
```

And these are some of the things I tried (that didn't work) get rid of NA's in father_age:

```
mutate(updated_dad_age = father_age %>%
  drop_na())

cor(baby_data$mother_age, baby_data$father_age, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Does anyone know how to get rid of NA's in the one variable, father_age, so I can compute a correlation?

Comment: if you share a sample of your data, e.g. with dput(baba_data) it would help answering your question. Usually somehting like this should work: ```bd <- baby_data %>% drop_na()```and then ```cor(bd$mother_age, bd$father_age)```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the mutate. You can do

```
baby_data <- baby_data %>% drop_na(father_age)
```

to just drop NAs for fathers or do drop_na() (as Wolfgang Arnold suggested) to drop all NAs in your tibble.